# Downloading from SourceForge gives me .class files instead of .java

Tags: java, sourceforge

I admit, I'm noob when it comes to sourceforge.  I'm trying to get the java files for http://jspellchecker.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jspellchecker/trunk/

Unfortunately, when I download the tarball it doesn't contain any `.java` files, they're all `.class`.

How can I get the .java files?

Comment: Maybe the tarball doesn't have the source. Check out the repo.

Comment: Sounds like you have found the binary distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this folder: http://jspellchecker.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jspellchecker/trunk/tinymce-spellchecker/src/org/tinymce/spellchecker/

[image]

Comment: I could've sworn I had downloaded that before and it was all .class files.... :sigh: